# How to convert an array of int to a vector?

Tags: c++

I would like to convert an array to a vector for more convenience, how do I do it, please ?
For example, with an array A, I tried the following :

```
std::vector<int> v(A.begin(), A.end())
```

but it doesn't work, I have the error :

> error: request for member 'begin' in 'A', which is of non-class type
> 'int*'

Comment: `int A []` is a normal array. It doesn't have a begin() and end() like `std::array`.

Comment: Can you show the declaration for `A`?

Comment: What is the definition of `A`?

Comment: It is int A[], if I understood I need to use the classe array from the STL, it is not even possible to browse the element of an array which is decayed to a pointer, right ?

Comment: Assuming `A` is actually an array (not a pointer) then (C++11 and later) do `std::vector<int> v(std::begin(A), std::end(A))`.    Before C++11 (or if `A` is a pointer, not an array) if the number of elements in `A` is `n` then do `std::vector<int> v(A, A + n)`.   This assumes the elements of `A` can be converted to `int`.

Comment: `int A[]` will be different if it is a parameter to a function so we need the details to be provided in your code.

Comment: ...Galik unless you pass `A` to an appropriate template function. That's how std::begin and std::end work on array types - no pointer decay there!

Answer (score 6):

You need

```
std::vector<int> v(std::begin(A), std::end(A));
```

`A`, as an array type, doesn't have member functions, so `A.begin()` and `A.end()` will cause the compiler to issue a diagnostic.

Note that `A` needs to be an array type, *not* an array that's decayed to a pointer.

Comment: I I get the error "no matching function for call to 'begin(int*&)'"

Comment: @ElezanHita: See the last sentence I've added.

Comment: @ElezanHita If `A` is a pointer and you don't know how many elements there are, then you can't use it like an array *for any purpose*.

Comment: I don't understand, how do I declare an array which is not decayed to a pointer ?

Comment: Thank you, but I would need to browse all element from that array, How do I do ?

Comment: `int A[2];` declares an array with 2 elements, for example.

Comment: @ElezanHita: If you have a pointer rather than an array, then you'll need some size information too, otherwise you don't know where the final element is. Another approach is to use a "magic value" which designates the final element. A C-style string adopts this approach, with the NUL terminator acting as the magic value.

Comment: @Bathsheba if I understood, this is ok the line "for(int i = 0; A[i] != NULL; ++i) v.push_back(A[i]) "

Comment: @ElezanHita: No it absolutely is not ok, unless you've explicitly written 0 in the final element of the array.